# Split variable from last slash

Tags: javascript

I have a variable `var1/var2/var3`. I want to store `var3` the part after last slash in a variable and the part before that (`var1/var2/`) in another variable. How can I do this?

Answer (score 153, accepted):

You can use `lastIndexOf` to get the last variable and that to get the rest.

```
var rest = str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
var last = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, str.length);
```

**Example on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markcoleman/Haudj/1/).**

```js
var str = "var1/var2/var3";

var rest = str.substring(0, str.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
var last = str.substring(str.lastIndexOf("/") + 1, str.length);
console.log(rest);
console.log(last);
```

Answer (score 32):

Try something like this:

```
var vars = "var1/var2/var3";
var arrVars = vars.split("/");
var lastVar = arrVars.pop();
var restVar = arrVars.join("/");
alert(lastVar);
alert(restVar);
```

Comment: This is a much better solution than the accepted one.

Comment: `vars.split("/").pop().join('/')` one liner shortcut :D

Comment: @PardeepJain `.pop` resolves to the last element, which happens to be a string. You cannot call `.join()` on a string.

Answer (score 20):

```
var last  = url.split("/").pop();
console.log(last);
```

You can get last piece of url with array pop method.

Answer (score 4):

Use this function:

```
function splitLast(s, sep = ' ') {
    /* Split `s` on the last occurrence of `sep` and return both parts 
       as an array, [left,right]; or return ["",s] if no occurrence was found. 
    */
    let right = s.split(sep).pop()
    let left  = s.substring(0, s.length - right.length - sep.length)
    return [left, right]
}
```

Call it like:

```
let [left, right] = splitLast('var1/var2/var3', '/')
// left:  "var1/var2"
// right: "var3"
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use a split and then pull the last index of it, like so :

**Example:**

```
var string = 'var1/var2/var3';

var result = string.split('/');         //Splits into an array

//var final = result[result.length -1]; //Grabs last value
//result.pop();                         //Removes last value

var final = result.pop();               //Removes last value and grap the last value
var previous = result.join('/');        //Grabs the previous part

alert("Previous: " + previous + ", Final Part: " + final);  //Alerts results
```

**Demo:**

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/5fSY3/2)

Comment: Will you have more slashes after the area that you want? If so, that could be a bit more complicated. If not, this should work for what you need.

Comment: would this work for URL parsing for the 'src' of an audio element?  I need to replace a URL that I know is in a similar format and then replace everything prior to the last slash with a new base URL.

Answer (score 3):

```
var txt = "var1/var2/var3";
txt = txt.split('/')

var Var1 = txt.pop();
var Var2 = txt[0]+'/'+txt[1];

alert(Var1);
alert(Var2);
```

Comment: Not helpful as the answer does not explain what will be contents of Var1 and Var2

Answer (score 2):

Solution using regex, might not be the fastest, but takes less space and might be more readable.

```js
"var1/var2/var3".split(/\/(?=[^\/]+$)/)
```

- `\/` – Match a slash
- `(?=` – If it's followed by

  - `[^\/]+` – Anything but slashes.
  - `$` – And the end of the string
- `)`

Comment: Haha using "regex" and "might be more readable" in the same sentence made my day xD

Answer (score 1):

**string.substring(start,end)**

where

**start = Required**. The position where to start the extraction. First character is at index 0

**end = Optional**. The position (up to, but not including) where to end the extraction. If omitted, it extracts the rest of the string

```
    var string = "var1/var2/var3";

    start   = string.lastIndexOf('/');  //console.log(start); o/p:- 9
    end     = string.length;            //console.log(end);   o/p:- 14

    var string_before_last_slash = string.substring(0, start);
    console.log(string_before_last_slash);//o/p:- var1/var2

    var string_after_last_slash = string.substring(start+1, end);
    console.log(string_after_last_slash);//o/p:- var3
```

OR

```
    var string_after_last_slash = string.substring(start+1);
    console.log(string_after_last_slash);//o/p:- var3
```

Answer (score 1):

With ES20, and new time coding, it is much simpler:

```
"asd/asdff/aksdmmf/uuu".split('/')["asd/asdff/aksdmmf/uuu".split('/').length -1]
```

it will provide you "uuu". Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to use javascript:

```
var str = "var1/var2/var3/var4/var5";
var splitted = str.split("/");
var first = "";
for (var i=0; i<splitted.length-1; i++) {
    first += splitted[i] + "/";
}

var second = "";
if (splitted.length > 0) {
    second = splitted[splitted.length-1];
}

alert(first); // var1/var2/var3/var4/
alert(second); // var5
```

edited:
but the shortest solution will be: `substring()` use

Comment: i may have more slashes, not 3 always

Answer (score 0):

You can also repeatedly do `replace()`, `split()`, and `join()` on the string to get the desired result

```js
let str = 'var1/var2/var3';

str = str.split('').reverse().join('').split(/\/(.+)/).map(x => x.split('').reverse().join('')).reverse().filter(x => x);

console.log(str);
```

Explanation:

```js
str
  .split('') /* ['v', 'a', 'r', '/', 'v', 'a', ...] */
  .reverse() /* ['3', 'r', 'a', 'v', '/', 'r', ...] */
  .join('') /* '3rav/2rav/1rav' */
  .split(/\/(.+)/) /* ['3rav', '2rav/1rav', ''] */
  .map(x => x.split('').reverse().join('')) /* ['var3', 'var1/var2', ''] */
  .reverse() /* ['', 'var1/var2', 'var3'] */
  .filter(x => x) /* ['var/var2', 'var3'] */
```

Answer (score 0):

Much simpler option:

```js
let text = "var1/var2/var3".split("/")[2];
console.log(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function splitLast(str, substring) {
  const index = str.lastIndexOf(substring);
  return [str.slice(0, index), str.slice(index + 1)];
}

console.log(
  splitLast("var1/var2/var3", "/")
);
```